# JSON-Pickle returns own iterator class as list iterator rather than itself

Tags: python, json, iterator, jsonpickle

I want to encode a Python class that is *iterable* as a JSON however JSON-Pickle returns it as just a list generator when decoding. This my code:

```
from typing import Iterable
from Helper import Helper
from RCEnum import RCEnum
import jsonpickle


class InnerTable:

def __init__(self, rows, cols):
    if not Helper.lio(int, rows, cols) or rows<1 or cols<1: raise Exception("Invaild rows and or cols")
    ret={"rows":[[None]*(cols+1)], "cols":[[None]*(rows+1)]}
    tid=[]
    self.rows=rows
    self.cols=cols
    for r in range(1, rows+1):
        ret["rows"].append([None])
        for c in range(1, cols+1):
            f=str(r)+"&"+str(c)
            tid.append((r, c))
            ret["rows"][-1].append(f)
            if c==len(ret["cols"]):
                ret["cols"].append([None, f])
            else:
                ret["cols"][c].append(f)
    self.table=ret
    self.tid=tid
    self.element=0

def __iter__(self):
    return self

def __next__(self):
    try:
        i=self.element
        self.element+=1
        return self[self.tid[i]]
    except IndexError:
         self.element=0
         raise StopIteration

def __len__(self):
    return self.cols*self.rows


def __getitem__(self, item):
    if item=="rows":
        return self.table["rows"]
    elif item=="cols":
        return self.table["cols"]
    elif isinstance(item, Iterable) and len(item)==2:
        if isinstance(item[0], bool) and isinstance(item[1], int):
            if item[0]:
                return self[self.tid[item[1]]]
            else:
                return self[self.tid[-item[1]]]
        if Helper.lio(int, item):
            return self[item[0]][item[1]]
    else:
        return self.table["rows"][item]

def changeElement(self, a, b, nv, loc="rows"):
    try:
        if not (loc.lower()==RCEnum.C.value or loc.lower()==RCEnum.R.value): raise IndexError("not a valid location ")
        loc2=RCEnum.C.value if loc.lower()==RCEnum.R.value else RCEnum.R.value
        self[loc][a][b]=nv
        self[loc2][b][a]=nv
    except Exception as e:
        print("Not changed. Reason "+str(e))

def getNFieldsInRoCAC(self, roc, l, direct=1, loc="rows"):
    if not (loc.lower()==RCEnum.C.value or loc.lower()==RCEnum.R.value): raise IndexError("not a valid location ")
    fields=self[loc][roc] if direct>0 else [None]+list(reversed(self[loc][roc]))[:-1]
    ret=[]
    alwaysNotIn=[]
    for ni in range(1, len(self[loc])):
        if ni==roc: continue
        alwaysNotIn.extend(self[loc][ni][1:])
    for i in range(1, len(fields)+1):
        if i+l>len(fields): break
        current=fields[i:i+l]
        currentNonFields=fields[1:i]+fields[i+l:]+alwaysNotIn
        ret.append([current, currentNonFields])
    return ret


def __repr__(self):
    return "InnerTable "+str(self.rows)+"*"+str(self.cols)

def __str__(self):
    rs=""
    for ri in self["rows"][1:]:
        rs+=str(ri[1:])+"\n "
    return rs

def toJSON(self):
    return  jsonpickle.encode(self)
```

The helper mostly implements the flatten-Method and a method that lets me check if every element in a list is of a certain type:

```
from typing import Iterable

class Helper:

    @staticmethod
    def flatten(items, useValues=True):
        """Yield items from any nested iterable; see Reference."""
        for x in items:
            if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, (str, bytes)):
                for sub_x in Helper.flatten(x.values() if isinstance(x, dict) and useValues else x):
                    yield sub_x
            else:
                yield x

    @staticmethod
    def lio(cl, *inst):
        inst=list(Helper.flatten(inst))
        return all(map(lambda i:isinstance(i, cl), inst))
```

RCEnum is surprise, surprise a simple enum:

```
from enum import Enum

class RCEnum(Enum):
    R="rows"
    r="row"
    C="cols"
    c="col"
```

But now to the important part:

```
it=InnerTable(1, 4)
it2=jsonpickle.decode(it.toJSON())
```

And for some reason it2 is no InnerTable but a list_iterator object, why? What can I do to correct this? (Note that removing the iterable function from InnerTable would be very unpleasant for me both for time reasons and because I see no reason why these 2 functions shouldn't go together.)

Comment: Note, you've created an *iterator* not a mere iterable. It also does not adhere to the iterator protocol, since it allows multiple passes

Comment: But isn't this usally the case (multiple passes I mean)? A list and so can do it too or not? Oh I see I should reset element before raising the StopException not in the iter-method right? Anyway my question more or less stays the same: how can I cast an iterator class to a json and back again in order to save an instance in a file?

Comment: In `InnerTable.__init__` you are calling `Helper.lio(int, ...` instead of `Helper.lio(self, ...` maybe

Comment: How would this help? lio should help check if rows and cols are postive integers, at most I should check it before comparing them to 1.

Comment: Lists and other containers aren't iterators, they are iterables. Iterators should be single pass. Consider `it = iter([1,2,3])`

Comment: Well but what if I need more than a single pass (I need to run it through with a for-loop at least  twice). But if the distinction between an iterator and and an iterable is how often you can pass, I don't get your correction from the first comment.